# The boxes on the mobile view of this page aren't centered and full width

Tags: html, css

The boxes on the services page aren't centered and aren't full width.

I have tried changing the `margin` to `0 auto` location, I have also tried `align-content: center`:

```css
ul#services li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: #cccccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.page-title {
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  header#bradning,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar,
  ul#services,
  main {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  #newsletter h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  #newsletter button,
  #sidebar-quote button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter form input[type="email"],
  #sidebar-quote input,
  #sidebar-quote textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <article id="main-col">
      <h1 class="page-title">Services</h1>
      <ul id="services">
        <li>
          <h3>Website Design</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $1,000 - $3,000</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Website Maintenance</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $250 per month</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Website Hosting</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $25 per month</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>

    <aside id="sidebar">
      <div class="dark">
        <h3>Get A Quote</h3>
        <form class="quote">
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Emial Address">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Message</label><br>
            <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="button_1" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

I expect the boxes to be centered and the same width as the get a quote section.

If anyone can help with this issue that would be great I am not sure what to do next, the site is functional as is but doesn't look as good as I was hoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want it like this right?

I just set some css property to `ul#services` see below

`#services{padding: 0;display: block; margin: 0 auto;}`

```css
ul#services li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: #cccccc solid 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

#services {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-title {
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  header#bradning,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar,
  ul#services,
  main {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  #newsletter h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  #newsletter button,
  #sidebar-quote button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #newsletter form input[type="email"],
  #sidebar-quote input,
  #sidebar-quote textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <article id="main-col">
      <h1 class="page-title">Services</h1>
      <ul id="services">
        <li>
          <h3>Website Design</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $1,000 - $3,000</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Website Maintenance</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $250 per month</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Website Hosting</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies at, vulputate id lorem. Nulla facilisi.</p>
          <p>Pricing: $25 per month</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>

    <aside id="sidebar">
      <div class="dark">
        <h3>Get A Quote</h3>
        <form class="quote">
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Emial Address">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Message</label><br>
            <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="button_1" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you, if you don't mind my asking what are the specific changes you made just so I know for the future.

Comment: @macatwork you just beat me to it.. a good answer requires at least a brief explanation so that it can also be useful for future readers.

Comment: sorry i did't mansion the changes i just add this css`#services{
padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`